# Getting 500 internal server error on Unleashed put request with python

Tags: python, api, request, put

I am using the following code to update sales order on unleashed but it's not working, It's returning internal server error. It's working for get request.

```
import requests.auth
import json
import requests
import binascii
import hashlib
import hmac

unleashed_api_app_id = 'xxxxxxx'
unleashed_api_app_key = 'xxxxxx'

class UnleashedAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):

    def __init__(self, api_id, api_key):
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_key = api_key

    def get_query(self, url):
        parts = url.split('?')
        if len(parts) > 1:
            return parts[1]
        else:
            return ""

    def __call__(self, r):
        query = self.get_query(r.url)

        hashed = hmac.new(self.api_key, query, hashlib.sha256)
        signature = binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest())[:-1]

        r.headers['api-auth-signature'] = signature
        r.headers['api-auth-id'] = self.api_id
        return r


a = UnleashedAuth(unleashed_api_app_id, unleashed_api_app_key)

h = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

i = {
    "SalesOrderLines": [
        {
            "LineNumber": 1,
            "LineType": None,
            "Product": {
                "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ProductCode": "SHELF",
                "ProductDescription": "Bookshelf Shelf"
            },
            "DueDate": "\/Date(1597190400000)\/",
            "OrderQuantity": 10,
            "UnitPrice": 120,
            "DiscountRate": 0.02,
            "LineTotal": 1176,
            "Volume": None,
            "Weight": None,
            "Comments": "",
            "AverageLandedPriceAtTimeOfSale": 86.3,
            "TaxRate": 0,
            "LineTax": 0,
            "XeroTaxCode": "NONE",
            "BCUnitPrice": 117.6,
            "BCLineTotal": 1176,
            "BCLineTax": 0,
            "LineTaxCode": None,
            "XeroSalesAccount": None,
            "SerialNumbers": None,
            "BatchNumbers": None,
            "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1597142565050)\/"
        },
        {
            "LineNumber": 0,
            "LineType": "Charge",
            "Product": {
                "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ProductCode": None,
                "ProductDescription": "10"
            },
            "DueDate": "\/Date(1597190400000)\/",
            "OrderQuantity": 1,
            "UnitPrice": 20,
            "DiscountRate": 0,
            "LineTotal": 20,
            "Volume": None,
            "Weight": None,
            "Comments": None,
            "AverageLandedPriceAtTimeOfSale": None,
            "TaxRate": 0,
            "LineTax": 0,
            "XeroTaxCode": None,
            "BCUnitPrice": 20,
            "BCLineTotal": 20,
            "BCLineTax": 0,
            "LineTaxCode": "NONE",
            "XeroSalesAccount": None,
            "SerialNumbers": None,
            "BatchNumbers": None,
            "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "LastModifiedOn": None
        }
    ],
    "OrderNumber": "xxxxxxxx",
    "OrderDate": "\/Date(1597104000000)\/",
    "RequiredDate": "\/Date(1597190400000)\/",
    "CompletedDate": None,
    "OrderStatus": "Completed",
    "Customer": {
        "CustomerCode": "PTECH",
        "CustomerName": "PivacTech",
        "CurrencyId": 48,
        "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1597142415046)\/"
    },
    "CustomerRef": None,
    "Comments": None,
    "Warehouse": {
        "WarehouseCode": "MAIN",
        "WarehouseName": "Main Warehouse",
        "IsDefault": True,
        "StreetNo": None,
        "AddressLine1": None,
        "AddressLine2": None,
        "Suburb": None,
        "City": None,
        "Region": None,
        "Country": None,
        "PostCode": None,
        "PhoneNumber": None,
        "FaxNumber": None,
        "MobileNumber": None,
        "DDINumber": None,
        "ContactName": None,
        "Obsolete": False,
        "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1597121276596)\/"
    },
    "ReceivedDate": None,
    "DeliveryInstruction": None,
    "DeliveryName": "Test",
    "DeliveryStreetAddress": "#test house",
    "DeliveryStreetAddress2": None,
    "DeliverySuburb": "Test ",
    "DeliveryCity": "Test",
    "DeliveryRegion": "Test",
    "DeliveryCountry": "India",
    "DeliveryPostCode": None,
    "Currency": {
        "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
        "Description": "United Kingdom, Pounds",
        "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1597012885460)\/"
    },
    "ExchangeRate": 1,
    "DiscountRate": 0.02,
    "Tax": {
        "TaxCode": "NONE",
        "Description": None,
        "TaxRate": 0,
        "CanApplyToExpenses": False,
        "CanApplyToRevenue": False,
        "Obsolete": False,
        "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModifiedOn": None
    },
    "TaxRate": 0,
    "XeroTaxCode": "NONE",
    "SubTotal": 1196,
    "TaxTotal": 0,
    "Total": 1196,
    "TotalVolume": 0,
    "TotalWeight": 0,
    "BCSubTotal": 1196,
    "BCTaxTotal": 0,
    "BCTotal": 1196,
    "PaymentDueDate": "\/Date(1600560000000)\/",
    "AllocateProduct": True,
    "SalesOrderGroup": "Website",
    "DeliveryMethod": "Delivery",
    "SalesPerson": {
        "FullName": "test name",
        "Email": "test email",
        "Obsolete": False,
        "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1534049276566)\/"
    },
    "SendAccountingJournalOnly": False,
    "SourceId": None,
    "CreatedBy": "test email",
    "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1597122197737)\/",
    "LastModifiedBy": "test email",
    "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "LastModifiedOn": "\/Date(1597142565062)\/"
}
guid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
unleashed_api_url = 'https://api.unleashedsoftware.com/SalesOrders/'+str(guid)

resp = requests.put(
    unleashed_api_url,
    i,
    auth=a,
    headers=h,
)
print("resp2===", resp.text)
```

Following is output it returns:
('resp2===', u'{"Description":"There was an internal server error.","DebugInformation":null}')

The same code is working using their sandbox but not working with my local request.

Comment: "internal server error" indicates a fault on their side, not yours. (At the very least, their system should give you a better error message.) You should contact them about it.

Comment: Thank you but one another problem the same request is working with curl but not working with python request put, is that also their server problem or problem on my data